# OpenVPN routing based in LDAP Authentication?

Tags: routing, ldap, openvpn

To understand the solution better this is an example:

- The company has 1000 users that constantly switch seats (computers are set with DHCP IP, so the user can constantly have his IP address changed) and teams (LDAP group).
- Each team (LDAP group) has access to specific VLAN's
- How to write routing rules based on user's ldap group ?

I want to build a VPN solution that will work like this:

- The VPN will be used inside a LAN only. No internet or remote servers ...
- The VPN Server has access to all private VLANs and to the default user's VLAN (1).
- I will use a LDAP Server to authenticate/authorize users.
- Based on client's LDAP groups, the VPN server will allow/denied traffic to the private VLANs.

So I thought that a VPN with configurations that I described will work in this scenario. Is it possible to build a solution like this using OpenVPN ? How? 
New ideas are welcome. Thanks.